# Getting id of selected item in listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I got a application with a listView in which I setup data from my sqlite database. My CustomCursorAdapter is placing the data (from the DBAdapter) in the listview.
I want to get the item id of the selected item from my listView, I got it working via this code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
             int position, long id) {
           // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
           Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

           //Get it from the database.
           String countryCode = 
           cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0)));
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
          });
```

That code does get the ID and makes a toast in which I can see the ID. This works perfectly. 
Now I want to put it in a context menu in which I long click the item (so this method does not start). I have the context menu working with the items, but I only need to get the id of which item in the listview is selected.

This is now my code for the context menu:

```
     public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);


       String countryCode = 
       cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0)));


      switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM:

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   return(true);
             case CONTEXT_MENU_UPDATE:

                   return(true);    
      }
  return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

The context menu does not work now because the position variabele is not set. I really dont know how to get the selected item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item .getMenuInfo();   
int positionSelected = menuInfo.position;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just implement onItemLongClick as you implement onItemClick and register this listview for context menu.

In long click get the index through this get the selected id and in context menu use this ID.

Another way is in this link check out link

http://progrnotes.blogspot.in/2010/10/android-context-menu-in-listview-after.html

here is snippet code of menu

```
@Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
      Long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);/*what item was selected is ListView*/

      switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE_ITEM:
                    //do smth
                   return(true);
             case CONTEXT_MENU_UPDATE:
                   //do smth else)
                   return(true);   
      }
  return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView tlls you this via [AbsListView.getCheckedItemIds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds%28%29)

HTH